# REGULAR EXPRESSION for initcap in sap hana

Tags: sql, hana

We are using SAP HANA 1.0 SPS 12.
AS SAP HANA does not have INTICAP function like oracle, I am trying to realize the same through REGEXP_REPLACE.

Basically I want first letter of each string as UPPER CASE.

In oracle it is possible as -

```
select initcap('abc') from dual ---- Output -'Abc'
```

In SAP HANA I am trying -

```
SELECT REPLACE_REGEXPR('([[:alnum:]]{1})([[:alnum:]])' IN 'abc' WITH 'upper(\1)\2') "replace_regexpr" FROM DUMMY;
```

But this is not working? Is it possible to realize this with REGEXP_REPLACE?

Comment: Just adding: with SAP HANA 2 SP03 there is an INITCAP() function available in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CONCAT(upper(substring(col1,1,1)),substring(col1,2,length(col1)-1)) from 
yourTable
```